# finding a substring in a text column that start and end with a specific string

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to scan a text dataframe column and retrieve a string that starts with a specific string and ends with a specific string.I tried to use substring with instr but couldn't get it working.

Comment: Post your code. It's usually easier to fix code that doesn't work than to write fresh code to vague specifications.

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is use regex and pattern matching to achieve this

```
@ def getText(startsWith: String, endsWith: String)(text: String): (String, String) = {
    val rr = s"($startsWith(.+?)$endsWith)".r
    text match {
      case rr(all, partial) => (all, partial)
      case _ => ("", "")
    }
  } 
defined function getText

@ getText("1", "2")("1hdfjhsdf2") 
res5: (String, String) = ("1hdfjhsdf2", "hdfjhsdf")
```

this should do what you want